# gpg-agent can't be reached

Tags: 16.04, gnupg

On a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install, I would like to use gpg to cypher my database backups, but I can't have the `gpg-agent` working.

```
postgres@db:~$ gpg -s test.txt

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Nicolas Remond <nicolas@xxx.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID F5DECA47, created 2016-11-03

gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
Enter passphrase:
```

Also, it seems that a gpg-agent is running as I did the following before:

```
postgres@db:~$ gpg-agent
gpg-agent[1715]: no gpg-agent running in this session
postgres@db:~$ gpg-connect-agent /bye
gpg-connect-agent: no running gpg-agent - starting '/usr/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (5s)
gpg-connect-agent: connection to agent established
postgres@db:~$ pidof gpg-agent
1762
```

And the gpg config has the `use-agent` setting:

```
postgres@dbmaster0:~$ cat ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf | grep use-agent
# For Ubuntu we now use-agent by default to support more automatic
use-agent
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Start the agent with `--log-file [myfile]` and see if it gives you any errors in the log.

Comment: The right error message I have is `gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session`. If I had a log how you suggest, all I have get is : `2016-12-19 13:39:39 gpg-agent[10957] gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.1.11 started`

Comment: I tried to manually set `GPG_AGENT_INFO`, but I don't know how to know what to set ... that's when I got a `gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use`.

Comment: As root, setting `export GPG_AGENT_INFO=/var/lib/postgresql/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1` works, but not as a user. Also, it seems that I would have to do that manually, no?

Comment: Did you add this __GPG_TTY=$(tty)  export GPG_TTY__ to your __.bashrc__ file as stated in the _man gpg-agent page ?

Comment: Could you please check if you have an agent running for your user already with `pgrep -xu "$USER" gpg-agent`? What's the value of the `GPG_AGENT_INFO` environment variable (check with `echo "$GPG_AGENT_INFO"`)? Depending on the outcome I'll ask further questions.

Comment: @George: Indeed, I did had it already

Comment: @DavidFoerster: `pgrep -xu "$USER" gpg-agent` gives me `8572` and the `GPG_AGENT_INFO` is empty, which I don't understand why?

Comment: Ok, that's a good start for an investigation. Let's make sure that `gpg-agent` can work at all. Please terminate the existing agent (`pkill -xu "$USER" gpg-agent`), start a new one and have your shell “source” its output: `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)`. Then try to use the agent, e. g. with `gpg -s some-file`.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46960/how-to-configure-gpg-to-enter-passphrase-only-once-per-session

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answering myself in case someone else is stuck on this.

On Ubuntu 16.04, the default versions are:

```
    # gpg --version
    gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20
```

and

```
    # gpg-agent --version
    gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.1.11
```

They are not compatible. It is mandatory to use GPG2:

```
    # gpg2 --version
    gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to install `gpgv2` :

```
sudo apt install gpgv2
```

This is because gpg-agent that comes with Ubuntu is version 2 and it tries to connect to gpg with version 2. But Ubuntu has gpg version 1 installed.

Comment: probably you meant `gnupg2`

Comment: No, it only worked after installing `gpgv2`. I tried with `gnupg2` but it didn't work.